# Understanding 'sed' command

Tags: bash, shell, gcc, sed, makefile

I am currently trying to install GCC-4.1.2 on my machine: Fedora 20.

In the instruction, the first three commands involve using 'sed' commands, for Makefile modification. However, I am having difficulty in using those commands properly for my case. The website [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/general/gcc.html) for GCC-4.1.2.

The commands are:

```
sed -i 's/install_to_$(INSTALL_DEST) //' libiberty/Makefile.in &&
sed -i 's@\./fixinc\.sh@-c true@' gcc/Makefile.in &&
sed -i 's/@have_mktemp_command@/yes/' gcc/gccbug.in &&
```

I am trying to understand them by reading the 'sed' man page, but it is not so easy to do so. Any help/tip would be appreciated!

Comment: You didn's specify why should you install an old version of `gcc` and why you expect `linuxfromscratch.org` to be a good source for installing it on Fedora. On the other hand, you didn't specify what exactly and why are you trying to achieve with `sed` here.

Comment: @ pavel Simerda: I am trying to install gcc-4.1.2, because I am trying to run a program which fails at running in the newer version. I chose the provided website, because that was the only link I could find. (Please share if you know a good source?) If I knew what the 'sed' commands were used to achieve, I wouldn't have asked a question here: Yet, I didn't share listed information, because it was not directly related to my question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the program to build with the current `gcc`? The changes are usually not so fatal and it sounds much safer to me than playing with an old version of a compiler. And this way you could create a regular Fedora 20 package which is then much more convenient than a manual build. But if you want help with that, it would be probably better to start a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you completely on that I should change the program rather than the compiler. The program was written by someone else. It's a fairly big code. And I am not strong enough programmer to figure out what causes the dependency problems. (Would I get answers if I ask a big question like this ...?)

Comment: If you are ready to take the effort to fix the program, I guess you will mostly get trivial errors that you can fix yourself. In cases where it's not so trivial, it would be good to post one question at a time with only the specific couple of lines involved. When changing a compiler, one usually gets warnings rather than errors. You should probably check your compiler command line and change the build system so it doesn't include `-Werror` which changes warnings into errors.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. I will look into follow your instruction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the shell part: `&&`.  That just chains the commands together, so each subsequent line will only be run if the prior one is run successfully.

`sed -i` means "run these commands inline on the file", that is, modify the file directly instead of printing the changed contents to STDOUT.  Each sed command here (the string) is a **substitute** command, which we can tell because the command starts with `s`.

*Substitute* looks for a piece of text in the file, and then replaces it.  So the order is always `s/needle/replacement/`.  See how the first and last lines have those same forward-slashes?  That's the traditional delimiter between the command (substitute), the needle to find in the haystack `(install_to_$(INSTALL_DEST)`, and the text to replace it with ().

So, the first one looks for the string and *deletes* it (the empty replacement).  The last one looks for `@have_mktemp_command@` and replaces it with `yes`.

The middle one is a bit weird.  See how it starts with `s@` instead of `s/`?  Well, sed will let you use any delimiter you like to separate the needle from the replacement.  Since this needle had a `/` in it (`\./fixinc\.sh`), it made sense to use a different delimiter than `/`.  It will replace the text `./fixinc.sh` with `-c true`.

Last note: Why does the second needle have `\.` instead of `.`?  Well, in a **Regular Expression** like the needle is (but not used in your example), some characters are *magical* and do *magical fairy dust* operations.  One of those magic characters is `.`.  To avoid the magic, we put a `\` in front of it, escaping away from the magic.  (The magic is "match any character", and we want a literal period.  That's why.)

Comment: @ heptadecagram: Thank you very much for your kind response. You provided the exact answer that I was looking for, especially regarding the 'flexible delimiters'.